# how to start a non producing block and connect to block producer?

Tags: nodeos, javascript

I have an application which requires to perform many transactions and I want some non block producing node to connect the BP nodes? I want to start non-producing blocks and connect to block producing nodes.

Comment: why can't you just send them with `cleos -u <bp-api-address>` without running a node?

Comment: I want to do this with using javascript sdk cleos is more CLI method to do this I want an running application to perform this for me

Comment: You can use community public endpoints to perform operations on chain. You can run your node as well if you want. As you want to communicate with chain via javascript, its worth exploring the eosjs-api, you can use any javascript rest client as eos provides rest endpoints. https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-api

Answer (score 1):

Create a non producer node and then to connect it to net,
You can follow this link to understand:
https://steemit.com/eos/@fundurian/learning-diary-connecting-to-eos-mainnet

This tutorial helps in connecting to mainnet, if you wish to connect to testnet you can follow the same steps as mentioned in the tutorial.
But, modify **config.ini** for nodeos and **genesis.json** to testnet configurations.
You can check out Jungle-Testnet for that.
Check out: http://jungle.cryptolions.io/#p2p

for P2P peer addresses on testnet.

I hope this helps!